# Pythons Multiprocess on Windows in a Package

Tags: python, multiprocess

I am trying to use multiprocess on windows but I am encountering the infinite loop error. Now I know this can be fixed by using the **name** == "**main**" in a standard python script. My problem is I am packaging the script so **name** is equal to "testmultiprocess" (The package name).

I have created a small project on [github](https://github.com/niallm90/testmultiprocess) to demonstrate my issue as it requires multiple files and an install.

Thanks,
Niall

Edit:

test.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def testFunction():
    print "testFunction"

def main():
    print __name__
    p = Process(target=testFunction)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

**name** that is printed is allways "testmultiprocessing" as it is the package name

Comment: post here your code which represent your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by patching the script created in the python directory that runs my package.

**C:\Python27\Scripts\testmultiprocess-script.py**

from:

```
sys.exit(
    load_entry_point(.....)
)
```

to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 sys.exit(
     load_
```